# Share video from Android raw folder to any app

Tags: java, android

I am making one app to allow user to share all video from any sharing app. My issue is file attached successfully but the file content is not attaching. below is my full source code. Let me know where I am making a mistake.

```
private void shareVideo() {

Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");

Uri localUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(CorporateAdaptor.this.rawVideoId + ".mp4"));

String str = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(localUri.toString()));
localIntent.setType(str);
localIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");

if (str == null) {
    str = "*/*";
}

localIntent.setType(str);
localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", localUri);

CorporateAdaptor.this.mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(local Intent, "Where you want to share?"));

}
```

This is my code that was I am using when user click on the share button. It will open a share dialog and when I select the gmail app, the file is attached but it's showing me a toast message "Couldn't find attachment". And when I click on send email file was not sending.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that `new File(CorporateAdaptor.this.rawVideoId + ".mp4")` is going to point to an actual file. If `rawVideoId` is the ID of a raw resource, that *definitely* is not going to point to an actual file, as resources are not files. Either copy the resource to a file and use `FileProvider` to get a shareable `Uri`, or use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) to try to stream the resource directly as a shareable `Uri`.

Comment: Thanks this link work perfectly. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider